# Count array_keys in strings from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have word array like: `$array = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];`

And seccond array: `$array = ['w', 'o'];`

I need to get number of replies from first array with chars from seccond like - how much W is in WORD1 and how much O is in WORD1. I want to do this in foreach from first array but i don't now how to fast count chars in string.

Comment: `substr_count` this function you need

Comment: The way to do it depends of the structure you want to obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do that with the following code, using `substr_count` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

```
<?php

 $array = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5'];
 $array1 = ['w', 'o', 'f' ,'d', 'p'];

  foreach ($array1 as $letter) {
   foreach ($array as $word) {
     echo "in " . $word . " there is " . substr_count($word, $letter) . $letter ."<br>";
   }
  }

?>
```